# Sort an array of a model Yii Framework

Tags: arrays, sorting, yii, model

Hi I'm currently working on a proyect that isn't mine on Yii Framework, I have this consulting the database

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new CoronaTrabajos('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['CoronaTrabajos'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_GET['CoronaTrabajos'];
    }
    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

That model have a field called 'fecha_publicacion' that is a date type, I want to sort the values ascending or descending based on that field, but I cannot find a way to do it, I'm new working with Yii, I have searched the documentation but still haven't a clear answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from CoronaTrabajos model search function. inside search function add order condition like below.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
....
//add there below line
$criteria->order = 'fecha_publicacion DESC';
...
...
```

Thats it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm just working on this proyect and never used Yii before, and is way more different that Laravel (what I'm used to)

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

To enable ASC and DESC sorting on a column, you must defined it in model like this

```
$sort = new CSort;
/* Sort criteria */
$sort->attributes = array(
            'col_name'=>array(
                'asc'=>"col_name", //you can add special logic too
                'desc'=>"col_name desc",
           ),
           '*' //adds all other columns,
       );
```

Then return your $sort with the DataProvider,

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'pagination'=>false,
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>$sort,
        ));
```

Also If you want to add default sort then

```
$sort->defaultOrder= array(
    'col_name'=>CSort::SORT_ASC,
);
```

Hope it helps.